# Access JSON to DICT in Python

Tags: python

I have the next JSON in JS

```
var intervalos= {
          "operandos":[{
             "extremoInferior":$(edit_numvar).context.value,
             "extremoSuperior":$(edit_numvar2).context.value
          },
          {
             "extremoInferior":$(edit_numvar3).context.value,
             "extremoSuperior":$(edit_numvar4).context.value
          }]
};
```

and I did    `parsed_input = json.loads(self.intervalos)`

but now I don't know how to access to my dict. I tried with

```
intervalos[operandos][extremoInferior])
```

but it returns an error.

Could you help me for accessing to any element of my dict?

Comment: after you parse your data, you assign it to `parsed_input`. So you have to use **that variable** to retrieve your data. Rest is dictionary and list operation.

Comment: The keys to the dictionary are strings. Use them.

Answer (score 2):

After deserializing JSON to Python object you could simply access to elements. For example:

```
parsed_input = json.loads(self.intervalos)
extremo_inferior_0 = parsed_input['operandos'][0]['extremoInferior']
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:

```
import simplejson as json

json_string = """{"operandos":[
                    {
                        "extremoInferior":"somevalue1",
                        "extremoSuperior":"somevalue2"
                    },
                    {
                        "extremoInferior":"somevalue3",
                        "extremoSuperior":"somevalue4"
                    }]
                }"""

json_data = json.loads(json_string)

print "Complete Dict: "
print json_data

print "operandos -> extremoInferior: "
print json_data['operandos'][0]['extremoInferior']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
intervalos['operandos'][0]['extremoInferior']
```

or

```
intervalos['operandos'][1]['extremoInferior']
```

`intervalos['operandos']` is defined as an array of two of these objects.

Comment: You can not get values form `intervalos` since it is not a python object!

Comment: Yes, you are right - I just wanted to indicate that he forgot the  "Array" level in his original question. (intervalos[operandos][extremoInferior])